# Custom Phong Shader for THREE.JS Object

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

Goal:  Calculate normals in the vertex shader for displaced vertices.

Current State:  Some hacky code that I don't believe is 100% correct.

--- progress ---

vert is the modified position of the vertex

vertNormal is the modified position of the vertex applied to the normals ( basically a clone )

```
vec3 objectNormal = normalize(cross(vert-position,vertNormal-position)); 
vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix * objectNormal;
vNormal = normalize( transformedNormal );
```

http://fallingcode.com/servedFiles/normals.jpg

I just need some feedback about that part of the vertex shader code at this point.

Comment: (1) What does "doesn't work" mean? (2) You are displacing the vertices. You will have to handle the normals, too, somehow. (3) You need to displace the vertices/normals first-thing, so the lighting calculations are computed using the modified vertices and normals.

Comment: (1) Doesn't work as in the envmap is not visible on the waving plane.  (2) I figured that, but would that stop the envmap from showing on the plane?  (3) Can I displace the normals in the same way I displaced the vertices?

Comment: (re: 2) Your normals all point in the same direction, so the lighting will be incorrect. Presumably, you'd still see something, however. (re: 3) Since you have analytical formulas for the displaced vertices, there is an implied analytical formula for the normals, too. What are you trying to create -- flat (faceted) shading or smooth shading?

Comment: Yea, I see something, but I can tell it isn't correct.  I want smooth shading.  I'm guessing there's an equation I can put in the shaders to handle this.  I've been googling..

Comment: West, I added a picture to show the progress I made with the equation.  It's not so great, LOL..

Comment: Inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83XkHQkeeAI. I think you would be wise to try something simpler than your current demo and get something working -- then slowly improve it.

Comment: Yea, I already saw that "inspiration".  I'm getting close.  I just created my own shader using chunks from the THREEJS phong shader.  It was tedious but worth it because now my plane is lit correctly and my understanding of shader language has been boosted.  I just have to implement a way to compute the normals for correct shading/lighting.

Comment: Excellent. Do you want an answer, or do you want to figure it out yourself? :-)

Comment: Check out the last picture I just posted.  I just need a little guidance on how to correctly compute the normals.  I'm adding the code which made the normals you see in the latest image.  It's probably missing something.

Comment: You do not have a question I can answer, so here is some guidance for modifyiing the vertex shader: Assuming you have a function `displace()` that sets the displacement in the direction of the original normal, do this: `float df = displace( position ); vec3 displacedPosition = position + normalize( normal ) * df; float delta = 0.1; vec3 newNormal = vec3( df - displace( position + vec3( delta, 0, 0 ) ), delta, df - displace( position + vec3( 0, 0, delta ) ) ); newNormal = normalize( newNormal ); vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * newNormal );`

Comment: Damn, thanks!  I'll be updating this post..

Comment: One question, man, I'm new to the syntax of shader language, but I catch on quick.  One thing I'm not grasping is the displace function.  I feed it a vec3 and it returns a float.  How do I do that?

Comment: `float displace( in vec3 position ) { float amplitude = ... ; return amplitude; }.` The position is displaced in the direction of the original normal by an amount equal to the returned value of the function.

Comment: After creating a function, I have your code working.  I appreciate all this help!  I guess if I move a vertex in any other direction than along the normal ( z ), this code I have won't properly adjust the normals?  Also, what does the delta variable do exactly?

Comment: Do you remember how to estimate a slope? `( f(  x + delta ) - f( x ) ) / delta`. It serves a similar purpose. You should take the time to understand why the formula to estimate the surface normal is correct.

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  West, again, I appreciate this.  I just started learning shader code a couple days ago, so, yea, I have a lot to learn.  I'm pickin' up the syntax well, but the equations, matrices, and such is gonna take time..  but, hey, I have my first shader using per pixel lighting and calculating normals!

Comment: Only one thing happening here that is weird to me.  The normals seem to be flipping according to sine amp I'm applying to the normals..  Why would that be happening?

Comment: I do not know what you are doing.

Comment: It's OK, I'll handle it from here.  I appreciate everything.  Your information has helped me understand things.

Comment: I figured out that your code was for a normal moving along the Y axis, but in my case, the normal axis is the Z, so I fixed it.  I'll be answering my own question soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @WestLangley's help, I've reached my goal.  The waves in the image are just to show the result.  I'll have to research equations to make them more natural looking.

So, the normals are being calculated correctly and the environment reflection (a THREE.JS cubemap) is working correctly too.

http://www.fallingcode.com/servedFiles/calculatedNormals.jpg

The following code in the vertex shader is what calculates the normals after vertices have been moved along the normal (the z axis in this case).

```
// the displacement function
float displace( vec3 pos ) {
    float amplitude;
    amplitude = sin( pos.y + time ) * 0.1;
    return amplitude;
}

float df = displace( position );
vec3 displacedPosition = position + normalize( normal ) * df;

float delta = 0.01;
vec3 newNormal = vec3( df - displace( position + vec3( delta, 0, 0 ) ), df - displace( position + vec3( 0, delta, 0  ) ), delta );
newNormal = normalize( newNormal );

vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * newNormal );
```